# Symfony2: programmatically start session

Tags: php, session, symfony

I want a global listener in my app to redirect the user after the session has timed out.

I am listening to the `kernel.exception` event for the `SessionUnavailableException`:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception =  $event->getException();
    if ($exception instanceof SessionUnavailableException) {
        //start new session and set flash here...
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('homepage'));
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

This code is executed after the session has timed out. The problem is if I leave the code like this, the exception will fire in an endless cycle. I need to start and save the session here, but can't find how to do this...

Any help?

By the way, is this a clever way to achieve my goal?

Comment: How do you start new session here?

Comment: I thought you tried to create session here but it didn't run.
This function will be invoked before any controller, so if you don't have any session and try to redirect it to homepage, it will run in forever loop. You should create session before redirect, or you should redirect if it is not homepage action (get Request object from event: $event->getRequest()), and create session in homepage action.

Comment: @SonNguyen Do you know how to create the session programmatically?

Comment: In Symfony2, all setXXX methods of Session object will start new session if it is not ready. I think you can get session from container in listener like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807092/symfony2-event-listener) and set some variable into it: $session->set('foo', 'bar');
Hope it help you.

Comment: i dont know very much about it, but does 

$session = new Session();
$session->start();

work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can start the session adding the following code:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

and...

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
```

..then you can set the flash messages:

```
$session->getFlashBag()->add(
                    'warning',
                    'El tiempo de su sesión se ha agotado. Por favor, vuelva a ingresar al sistema.'
);
```